# Page won't load after .click() even when it display on the browser

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm trying to scrape this page `"https://www.seloger.com/list_beta.htm?tri=initial&enterprise=0&idtypebien=2,1&idtt=2,5&naturebien=1,2,4&cp=75"`

But when i use `.click()` on the first element of the search, the page is correctly loaded in the browser but I didn't get the `body` and all its child with `driver.find_element` method whereas get the url of the new loaded page let me find it without problem.
`driver.current_url` give me the first page, it's like `.click()` didn't load anything whereas the rendered is successfully loaded in the browser.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import visibility_of_element_located
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import pyautogui
import time


def cssconvert(tag):
    return '.'+tag.replace(' ', '.')


binary = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe'
options = Options()
options.set_headless(headless=False)
options.binary = binary
cap = DesiredCapabilities().FIREFOX
cap["marionette"] = True #optional
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, capabilities=cap, executable_path="C:\\Users\\chrys\\Desktop\\DataScientist\\Selenium\\geckodriver_true\\geckodriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.seloger.com/list_beta.htm?tri=initial&enterprise=0&idtypebien=2,1&idtt=2,5&naturebien=1,2,4&cp=75")

#time.sleep(2)
select = 'block__ShadowedBlock-sc-10w6hsj-0 ListContent__SmartClassifiedExtended-sc-1viyr2k-2 iddbNe classified__ClassifiedContainer-sc-1wmlctl-0 haLWMI Card__CardContainer-sc-7insep-7 jZkbME'
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(cssconvert(select)).click()
driver.find_element_by_id('js-descriptifBien')
```

```
    241             raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
--> 242         raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
    243 
    244     def _value_or_default(self, obj, key, default):

NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: [id="js-descriptifBien"]
```

if now i copy past the url :

```
driver.get('https://www.seloger.com/annonces/viagers/appartement/paris-11eme-75/belleville-saint-maur/145504325.htm?projects=2,5&types=2,1&natures=1,2,4&places=[{cp:75}]&qsVersion=1.0&bd=ListToDetail')
driver.find_element_by_id('js-descriptifBien').text
```

it's working.
As my purpose is to crawl all elements from the result research, i would know how to deal with it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read about selectors [here](https://screenster.io/selenium-locators-best-practices-7-helpful-tips-for-ui-testers/) and [here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/27978/what-makes-a-good-selenium-locator).

The problem is when you click on list item, it opens it in a new tab. You have to switch to it before any action. Here some example how to navigate between windows:

```
current_window = driver.current_window_handle
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".iddbNe"))).click()
wait.until(EC.new_window_is_opened)
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

With Selenium, solution can be collecting all links from the list and after navigate to them. For that you can use `.iddbNe a[name=classified-link]` css selector. After collecting all links from all required pages you can navigate to them and collect data.
Here is example how to do it for the first page:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# ...

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

# you can put loop to go throw all pages you need and add to the list
links = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".iddbNe a[name=classified-link]")))
for link in links:
    driver.get(link)
    # get you data
```

Better solution to scrape is to use [requests](/questions/tagged/requests). With code below is simple example how you can get 100 results in json format. In repanse you can find total number of results and use it to loop and collect all information you need:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'origin': 'https://www.seloger.com',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'ru,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8,tr;q=0.7',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) '
                  'Chrome/77.0.3865.90 Safari/537.36',
    'content-type': 'application/json',
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'authority': 'www.seloger.com',
    'referer': 'https://www.seloger.com/list_beta.htm?projects=2%2C5&types=2%2C1&natures=1%2C2%2C4&places=%5B%7Bcp'
               '%3A75%7D%5D&qsVersion=1.0&LISTING-LISTpg=2',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'dnt': '1',
}

params = (
    ('from', '0'),
    ('size', '100'),
    ('isSeo', 'false'),
)

data = '{"idPublication":null,"projects":[2,5],"types":[2,1],"natures":[1,2,4],"places":[{"label":"Paris",' \
       '"cities":null,"districts":null,"countries":null,"divisions":null,"subDivisions":["75"],"fakeCities":null}],' \
       '"searchAreas":null,"isochronePoints":null,"proximities":null,"withGeoloc":null,"price":null,' \
       '"groundSurface":null,"surface":null,"bedrooms":[],"rooms":[],"bedroom":null,"room":null,"sort":null,' \
       '"floor":null,"lastFloor":null,"hearth":null,"guardian":null,"view":null,"balcony":null,"pool":null,' \
       '"lift":null,"terrace":null,"cellar":null,"south":null,"parking":null,"box":null,"parquet":null,"locker":null,' \
       '"furnished":null,"disabledAccess":null,"alarm":null,"toilet":null,"bathtub":null,"shower":null,"hall":null,' \
       '"livingRoom":null,"diningRoom":null,"kitchen":null,"heating":null,"unobscured":null,"picture":null,' \
       '"exclusiveness":null,"priceChange":null,"privateSeller":null,"video":null,"vv":null,"enterprise":null,' \
       '"garden":null,"basement":null,"groundFloor":null,"houseboat":null} '

response = requests.post('https://www.seloger.com/list/api/externaldata', headers=headers, params=params, data=data)
print(response.text)
```

Comment: thank you, it work perfectly, Could you tell me how to display the requests because I don't how did you know what data is needed to put in .
It's look like an heavyless solution than navigate with selenium .

Comment: I used network tab in developer tools to find correct request with required data.